# JQuery event delegation: how to get the index of a JQuery Object in a Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an array full of jQuery Object - dom elements:

```
var tabComponet = new Class({
    var $tab = $("<div class='tab'></div>");
    var $container = $("<div id='container'></div>");

    var tabsArr = [];
    [a, b, c].each(function(){
      tabsArr.push($tab);
      $container.append($tab);
    });

    $container.on('click', '.tab', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var index = $(tabsArr).indexOf($(this));
  }
});
```

I created tabsArr to avoid when there are multiple components created by this Class above by then there will be multiple components contains .tab class thus using $('.tab') would not be working right, but it seems I could not simply put a $ sign on tabsArr to make this working. Also in the delegation, I should avoid using '.tab' as parameter too, right?

I googled about it, it may be because that everytime I use $ to make a JQuery object they would be not the same but just contain the same value, so $(this) is not in tabsArr, because tabsArr doesn't contain it but just the same value.

so how should I do this? how should I create a object that contains the exact tab elements that belong to its own component?

Comment: I think I found something close to what you want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14418839/2159528).

Answer (score 0):

When you create element, you obtain reference to this element. **Reference is not value**. Your code serves as nice example: when your for loop finishes, you will see only one element inside container no matter what..

Wrapping javascript element into jQuery always create new reference. When you compare two elements(and any non-primitive type) in javascript, you don't compare values(content), but their references. Fortunately you can use [get() method](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to obtain javascript direct reference to element!

```js
var $container = $("<div id='container'></div>");

var tabsArr = [];
for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
  let $tab = $("<div class='tab'></div>");
  tabsArr.push($tab.get(0));
  $container.append($tab);
};

$container.on('click', '.tab', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(tabsArr.indexOf(this));
});

$container.appendTo('body');
```

```css
.tab {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```